# Angular Material's mat-error showing on one way data binding

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

The following `mat-form-field` shows the `<mat-error>` even though `someValue` is declared and defined.

`<mat-form-field>
  <input [value]="someValue" [formControl]="someFormControl"/>
  <mat-error *ngIf="someFormControl.hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>`

I want to be able to prefill the input with `someValue` without the `<mat-error>` showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the very architecture of FormControl that can't be done "automatically"... as from the moment you touch a component the formcontrol checks it... (that's the very beauty of it...)

but you can circumvent it in multiple ways... like this:

*.component.ts

```
someFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);
someValue: String = 'aValue';
activated: Boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.someFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe((observer) => {
        this.activated=true;
    })
}
```

*.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [value]="someValue" [formControl]="someFormControl"/>
    <mat-error *ngIf="someFormControl.hasError('required') && activated">Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

but it gets pretty ugly if you have a lot of input fields